# Sharing encrypted data between JS and C#, for dummies

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

My team must share data between a localnet html/js app, and a server in the same net listening on a websocket.
The first idea was to simply send variables to the server with get

```
http://192.168.1.100:8080/var=hello
```

It's simple and works, but we must add a security level to the data exchange, encrypting all in Aes and then hexing the result to send it as plain string.

The best solution that we found is Crypto-JS https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/
We are able to follow the examples and encrypting/decrypting data inside the same js block, but are unable to decrypt the data on another software.

we do:

```
var text = "Message";
var password = "Secret Passphrase";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, password);

var EnText = encrypted.ciphertext; //returns the hexed/encrypted text
var Key = encrypted.key;
```

It doesn't work with the c# code running on the server, so we tried an online decrypting tool http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ passing both the password and the Key, but similarly returns unreadable text

JS generated value for reference

```
EnText: 5768c9b4d75e0cc32b610d9e6f518c36
Key: 005e316192f5162f7fd104ce2c9fe91de6c6f2977849dcd5878226022a7073be
```

What are we missing?

Comment: The best solution is to just use ssl. Use self-signed certificates, then install the certificate on your team's computers.

Comment: You would be better off switching to HTTPS for transport security which is presumably what your after given that your key is in the clear in your js file

Comment: This does not work for me, is it normal?
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
 <script>
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("abc", "password");

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "password");
  alert(decrypted);
 </script>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: SSL would be perfect, but we have no control on the deployed machines. The html/js part is sealed in a phonegap's app (so it's not possible to open the code and read the key etc), so the most pratical way is to encode the data js side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, the text is in hexadecimal.
Try decyphering it there:

http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/

Comment: We take it in count both in the c# code and in the online tools, but doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, my bad.
The js library uses a default argument when encrypting (the mode). Is it possible that it's not the same in the C# version?